# car::scatter3d in R - labeling axis better

Tags: r, scatter-plot, rgl

I'm using scatter3d and the 3 axes just have two endpoint values. how can I get labels throughout the entire axis, just like the normal plot() function does?

Comment: This seems very helpful but I'm having trouble doing it. If I type car:::scatter.default it returns : Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : object 'scatter.default' not found but car:::scatter3d.default returns the entire function. Do you I edit the scatter3d.default? When I add the if (axis.scales) code to the scatter3d.default I get an error that saying : Error in match.arg(id.method) : object 'id.method' not found? Do you have the full version of the code edits that I could use? Thanks!!

Comment: @Megan: That was my error: now fixed below. (Didn't see this because it wasn't under my answer or addressed to me.) Re: full code. I could but then the answer would be somewhat bulky. I'm not sure how the rest of the audience feels about "bulky" answers.

Comment: Note the full version of the code (with another tweak or two) is now linked from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231007/having-trouble-executing-the-edits-to-scatter3d-default/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oh well. I took it as a challenge.

Obviously you need to:

```
require(rgl)
require(car)
require(mgcv) # for the example
```

Copy the `car:::scatter3d.default` code and paste it back, assigning it to `scatter3d.default`.

Add these lines early in the code for `scatter3d.default`:

```
 showLabels3d <- car:::showLabels3d  
 nice <- car:::nice  
  # since you will be losing their connection to the unexposed fns in car
```

Then in the code block following the second `if(axis.scales){ ...}`, substitute this code:

```
 if (axis.scales) {
   x.labels <-  seq(lab.min.x, lab.max.x, 
                       by=diff(range(lab.min.x, lab.max.x))/4)
   x.at <- seq(min.x, max.x, by=nice(diff(range(min.x, max.x))/4))
      rgl.texts(x.at, -0.05, 0, x.labels, col = axis.col[1])

   z.labels <-  seq(lab.min.z, lab.max.z, 
                       by=diff(range(lab.min.z, lab.max.z))/4)
   z.at <- seq(min.z, max.z, by=diff(range(min.z, max.z))/4)
      rgl.texts(0, -0.1, z.at, z.labels, col = axis.col[3])

   y.labels <-  seq(lab.min.y, lab.max.y, 
                       by=diff(range(lab.min.y, lab.max.y))/4)
   y.at <- seq(min.y, max.y, by=diff(range(min.y, max.y))/4)
      rgl.texts(-0.05, y.at, -0.05, y.labels, col = axis.col[2])
                }
```

(You may need to replace the code for `scatter3d.formula` so that doesn't look in the `car` NAMESPACE for the routinely dispatched `scatter` method. I simply replaced the `scatter3d` call inside `car:::scatter3d.formula` with "scatter3d.default" so the interpreter would first look at the newly defined function.)

Edit: a better method than mucking with `scatter3d.formula` is to assign the `car` namespace/environment to the new function with this code:

```
environment(scatter3d.default) <- environment(car:::scatter3d.formula)
```

Then if you do this:

```
scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)
```

You get this (taken with a screenshot program)
[image]

Comment: Would like to be able to +more for the amount of effort you put in here.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: You probably have an idea how many errors I made in the process of figuring this out.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm having a bit of trouble running it. Is scatter3d the same as `scatterplot3d`? I presume you also need to run "data(Duncan)" before trying to plot.

Comment: No, `scatter3d` is in pkg:car and `scatterplot3d` is in pkg:scatterplot3d. I did not need to run data(Duncan) but if one did not run require(car) (or library(car)) , one might need to do so. The RGL version in pkg:car lets you interactively control the rotation of the axis and plot and the plane points and axis lables move together. `scatterplot3d` results in a static graphic. You cannot move it interactively and it also does not have a formula interface as far as I can tell.

Comment: Nice. Note you can use `rgl.snapshot` to generate images of `rgl` plot windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option that adds interior axis labels, from the help of `scatter3d`:

> axis.ticks
>
> if TRUE, print interior axis-“tick” labels; the default is FALSE. (The code for this option was provided by David Winsemius.)