# Having trouble executing the edits to scatter3d.default

Tags: r, scatter

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204972/carscatter3d-in-r-labeling-axis-better) seems very helpful but I'm having trouble doing it. If I type `car:::scatter.default` it returns: `Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : object 'scatter.default' not found`, but `car:::scatter3d.default` returns the entire function. Do I edit `scatter3d.default`? When I add the `if (axis.scales)` code to `scatter3d.default` I get an error saying: Error in match.arg(id.method) : object 'id.method' not found? Do you have the full version of the code edits that I could use?

Comment: It would be helpful to link this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204972/carscatter3d-in-r-labeling-axis-better

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(car)
source(url("http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/misc/scatter3d.R"))
scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)
```

You could also use `download.file` to grab the file and `source()` it locally.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, this code does not function if you add ellipsoid=T

Comment: scatter3d(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan, ellipsoid=T)
Error in scatter3d.default(X[, 2], X[, 1], X[, 3], xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab,  : 
  could not find function "ellipsoid"

Comment: Do you know why this might be?

Comment: it's because `ellipsoid` is looking for a function hidden in the `car` package.  If you edit `ellipsoid` to `car:::ellipsoid` within the function it should work (let me know if it does)

Comment: Oh right... I added ellipsoid<-car:::ellipsoid and then ran my code but got this: Error in if (ellipsoid) { : argument is not interpretable as logical. In my code I specify ellipsoid=TRUE which is logical so I'm not sure why it's returning an error saying that it isn't.

Comment: updated code.  The author of this function uses `ellipsoid` both as a logical (TRUE/FALSE) and as a function, which can work but is bad programming practice.  Rather than setting `ellipsoid <- car3d:::ellipsoid` I edited the specific places where `ellipsoid` was being used to call that function.  (Haven't tested it myself though.)

Comment: one thing I added to if (axis.scales){... is to change  x.label, y.labels, z.labels  to as.integer(x.labels), as.integer(y.labels), as.integer(z.labels) since many numbers dont divide evenly.

Comment: Hello, I have a follow up question and hope you can help. With the help of the code posted by Ben Bolker and Megan's hint on the integers I managed to produce this http://imgur.com/GLSAQjR However, as you can see the year labels are still not displayed correctly. They should range from 1990 to 2014 by intervals of 4 maybe. The underlying year data is also numeric. Why does the code at the McMasters page not work for that?