# rgl.postscript: file saved without varying text sizes

Tags: r, pdf, rgl

From @DWin and @Ben Bolker, we can change the scatter3d function in R to plot "prettier" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204972/carscatter3d-in-r-labeling-axis-better), however, saving the plot is a  trickier. `rgl.snapshot` saves the image as a png but to save a high resolution image (PDF) `rgl.postscript` must be used. Using `rgl.postscript` will not save the image with font/text size/axis sizes as specified (I edited the `scatter3d` function to increase text/axis sizes). `rgl.snapshot` works as it should so why doesn't `rgl.postscript`? Does anyone know an alternative saving method or is there a way to save the plot with larger text/axis etc?

Comment: Can you try installing the r-forge version (`install.packages("rgl",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org") and see if that makes a difference? The log at https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/?root=rgl&view=log says: `Revision 828 - Directory Listing; Modified Mon Jun 6 17:19:04 2011 UTC (6 months, 3 weeks ago) by murdoch; Respect font size in rgl.postscript calls`, and the change might (?) not have propagated to the CRAN version ...

Comment: yes, this is very helpful however, i believe it only works on windows or I could only get it functioning correctly on windows.

Comment: that's funny.  I didn't try it on Windows, only on Linux (I could try it on a Mac if that would be helpful)

Comment: No its ok, i switched to a windows machine, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

A simple example works for me with the a more recent version of `rgl` than the CRAN one (CRAN has 0.92.798, r-forge now has 0.92.836, this is with 0.92.829).  It looks like versions are numbered by SVN revision, so this is one version *after* the update mentioned in the comments above ...

```
library(rgl)
set.seed(1001)
n <- 20
text3d(runif(n),runif(n),runif(n),LETTERS[1:n],cex=seq(0.5,5,length=n))
rgl.postscript(file="tmp.ps")
```

However, a big warning is that the resulting PS, PDF, files etc. are a bit wonky. The bounding boxes are a little odd, although I could text-edit that manually. `ps2pdf` and `ps2png` mangled it .. `epstopdf` seems to have worked (these are all tools that are available on Linux boxes, don't know about for other OS).  In principle `rgl.postscript()` allows you to export as PDF, but it might be weird PDF ... StackOverflow doesn't recognize the file as being in a valid upload format.

```
R Under development (unstable) (2012-01-01 r58032)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

[snip]

other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.92.829
```

[image]

> 

Comment: Thanks for the wizardry! I've been struggling to get this to work correctly and I'm very close. To make a scatter3d plot, i had to make the plot and then add: mtext3d, axes3d and axis3d. Ironically, I found using rgl.postscript and saving it as a pdf worked best and it was the the ps files that came out wonky. I am now struggling to make the size of the points larger. I tried to use plot3d/points3d and adding it to the original plot but that failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm.  `plot3d(1:5,1:5,1:5,size=20)` gives big ugly squares for me. `spheres3d(1:5,1:5,1:5,radius=0.3)` gives nice shiny spheres (you wouldn't want to use spheres if you had thousands of points to plot, they're computationally intensive compared to the ugly squares).

Comment: It's unfortunate the edited version of the scatter3d function on your website will not work for me (text size/point size) when I save it as a pdf.

Comment: the best way that I found to make a higher quality scatter3d image, is editting the scatter3d function and using image magic to convert between image types. ie. convert -size 8x8 -pointsize 72 -resample 300 -sharpen 300x100 filename.png filename.tiff. woohoo