# How to plot a three dimensional sphere in R based on center and radius?

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

**How can one plot a sphere in R by providing a center point and a radius?**

For example, something like this:

```
sphere_3d(center=c(1,1,1), r=2))
```

The plot would appear on a three dimensional coordinate system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `spheres3d` in the `rgl` package for an interactive plot:

```
library(rgl)
spheres3d(x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, radius = 1)
```

There are many other ways, so what's going to be useful needs more input.

Comment: +1 thanks. Any idea of how to add a labelled coordinate system. I tried `axes3d()` which seems like a start, but it does not say what is x, y, and z. It would also be nice to be able to control the limits of the axes.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim: An old answer (and one to a derivative of rgl in package:car) and you've probably moved on, but it might help someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204972/carscatter3d-in-r-labeling-axis-better

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from [@mdsummer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12085187/180892)'s answer, this also adds axes.

```
library(rgl)
open3d()                                   # create new plot
spheres3d(x = 1, y = 1, z = 1, radius = 1) # produce sphere
axes3d()                                   # add x, y, and z axes
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`rgl`](http://www.stattler.com/article/three-dimensional-plots-using-rgl-package) package for making 3D plots.