# How to make a 3d plot of given spherical polar equation in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

Suppose, we have a polar equation in spherical coordinates:
  f(theta) = 1 + cos[2theta]

If we use Mathematica to make a 3D plot, we can do like this:

```
SphericalPlot3d[1+cos[2theta],{theta,0,pi},{phi,0,2pi}]
```

Now the question remains: "How can we do the same thing in R?"

The link for Mathematica is:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085095/how-to-plot-a-three-dimensional-sphere-in-r-based-on-center-and-radius

Comment: @Badger, That is for x,y,z , i am searching for r,theta,phi. Anyway thanks for the link

Comment: This is your question, so you are free to edit back the wrong terminology, if you are not interested in making the question useful (you should not complain about the downvotes any longer, though). [Polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) are 2D and what you have here are [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). The name of the Mathematica function is also somewhat suggestive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `plot3D` allows you to create 3D plots in R. It takes x, y, and z-coordinates as input, so one needs an additional step to convert the spherical coordinates to Cartesian. To do this step, I define a function as follows:

```
spher2cart <- function(r, theta, phi) {

   x <- r * sin(theta) * cos(phi)
   y <- r * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
   z <- r * cos(theta)

   return(list(x = x, y = y, z = z))
}
```

The next step is to define a mesh of values for the angles `theta` and `phi`. `plot3D` offers the function `mesh()` to do this easily.

```
library(plot3D)
theta <- seq(0, pi, length = 50)
phi <- seq(0, 2*pi, length = 50)
M <- mesh(theta, phi)
names(M) <- c("theta", "phi")
```

Then, the values for `r` (which corresponds to the first argument in Mathematica's `SphericalPlot3d`) can be calculated:

```
r <- 1 + cos(2 * M$theta)
```

As I already mentioned, we will need to express this in Cartesian coordinates:

```
cart <- spher2cart(r, M$theta, M$phi)
```

And finally, the plot is created:

```
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
surf3D(cart$x, cart$y, cart$z, border = "black",
       colkey = FALSE, bty = "f",
       phi = 20, theta = 30)
```

[image]

There are many options to `surf3D()` and you can read about them with `?surf3D`. Those that I used are:

- `border = "black"`: This turns on the grid of black lines.
- `colkey = FALSE`: Turn off the colour legend
- `bty = "f"`: Draw the full box of axes. Omit this, if you don't want the box.
- `phi = 20`, `theta = 30`: Change the angle from which you look at the plot

There is also a [vignette for plot3d](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) with many examples.

**EDIT:**
As a second example I show the same plot with  a few changes:

- The surface is coloured grey by using `col = "grey"` (other colours are also possible).
- Axis labels are turned off using `xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = ""`.

This leads to the following code and plot:

```
surf3D(cart$x, cart$y, cart$z, border = "black",
       colkey = FALSE, bty = "f",
       phi = 20, theta = 30,
       col = "grey",
       xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "")
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome! The downvotes might be due to the fact that the question was a bit chaotic: typos, no capitals, arbitrary line breaks, etc. The quality of a question had not only to do with what you ask, but also with how you ask.

Comment: Yes, we can. And if you had actually read the answer, you would know how: simply omit `bty = "f"`.